# DispalyFormat in MVC with razor not displaying right

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an editable page, I want to reformat most of the fields, let's say that I have 2 fields, Mileage and Price.
I need to display them in TextBoxFor

Model.cs

```
public class TestModel {
    [DisplayName("Mileage: ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:##,###,###}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public Int32 Mileage { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Price: ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public Int32 Price{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Index() {
        var model = new TestModel();
        model.Mileage=150000;
        model.Price=21900;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Index.cs

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Mileage, new { @class = "w200" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "w200" })
<input type="submit" />
```

}

Unfortunately I don't see neither the price nor the mileage being formatted.

Any help as soon as possible will be appreciated,

Answer (score 3):

Set `ApplyFormatInEditMode` to `true`

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:##,###,###}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
```

You may also want to switch to `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor` just in terms of MVC best practices, but its not related to your problem.

Comment: I tried it but it is giving the following exception:                    "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String' ".

Comment: @AlaaOsta you mean for the EditorFor stuff, or the ApplyFormatInEditMode?

Comment: it seems for the EditorFor stuff, if I change it to TextBoxFor the page will load fine but the value is not formatted at all.